# OneNote 2010 Add-In load problem

Tags: c#, add-in, office-interop, onenote

Googled out- could use some help here.

I followed this excellent tutorial here (http://www.malteahrens.com/#/blog/howto-onenote-dev/) and have created my own onenote 2010 addin, but I am having trouble getting it to STAY in onenote.  On first install of the addin, I open onenote and the addin is loaded just fine (registry shows load behavior 3).  I close onenote and then simply open it again and my addin is unloaded.  Onenote (options-addins-manage com addins) shows there was a load error with com, and the registry shows a load behavior of 2 (errored out).  The specific error is:

Load Behavior: Not loaded.  A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-In.

I can enable the plugin displaying this error and it works just fine again- until I restart the app.  Seems it just cant load from startup any time except after a fresh install.

Ive enabled logging from one of the links from the site above, and dont see anything interesting in the log.  I can't attach to dllhost.exe to debug because its not running.  So I don't know any way to even see what is wrong.

Anyone have any ideas how I can debug this load error or ideas of what it might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem- I was signing one of my assemblies and had renamed the assembly itself a bit ago.  Regenerating the strong assembly signing file fixes the issue.

Still it was trial and error to find, I was unable to find any useful log info that could have helped, so that sux.