# OneNote 2013 Add-in won't load. How to debug?

Tags: com, office-interop, onenote

I'm following the [excellent tutorial by Malte Ahrens](http://www.malteahrens.com/#/blog/howto-onenote-dev/) on how to create a OneNote add-in.

Initially I followed it step by step, making a few changes (just renaming the class, and using my own name and GUID in the assembly) info. As I'm using VS2012 and am not yet ready to hand-roll a WiX installer I manually copied over the built dll to the correct place and also created a registry file to make the requisite entries. I confirmed that they were all there, loaded up OneNote but no add-in, going to "mange COM addins" section I saw the following error:

[image]

*Load Behavior: Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in.*

I spent some time debugging this but didn't get very far. So this afternoon I decided to start again but copy his code verbatim. I simply downloaded the example project, used the trial of [Vdproj to Wix](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f8ff662-c844-4c3c-9c7b-b170cea16baf) to create the installer and built everything.

I get the exact same error.

**Why is this please? What does this mean and most importantly how do I debug the problem?**

A few specifics about my environment and where it may differ from the original tutorial.

I am running Office 2013 AND it's 64bit. His tutorial is for 2010. This means when I loaded up the demo solution I had to remove the non-existent reference to the Onenote 14 Interop and add the v15 version.

In terms of registry entries they go to the right place, not the WOW6432 registry nodes. I doubly know this as if I load up OneNote and then refresh the HKCR registry node for the add-in, the LoadBehavior switches to 0x00000002, (disabled).

Other things that may be worth noting.

I have enabled OneNote logging and it's quiet on my issue.

There are 2 other posts on here with a seemingly similar problem (but Office 2010) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269588/onenote-2010-add-in-load-problem) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6552425/onenote-com-addin-only-loads-manually), neither got a response. The first guy had it loading once, but then had to manualy start it each time, mine never loads (and I've not signed my assembly) the second guy never got a response.

As I say, even knowing how to debug this further would be a great step forwards.

Edit:

I've gone back to debugging my own version, which is almost identical anyway as I'm not sure what the installer is actually doing and I think because it's a demo of the wix converter it's only allowing me to build for x86.

If I add OneNote.exe under "start external program" and run debug on my add-in, I see the following lines appear when I try and tick the add-in under "manage COM add-ins" within OneNote. I'm afraid I'm still pretty green at all this so I'm not sure what it means.

```
First-chance exception at 0x00007ffe4f86ab78 in ONENOTE.EXE: 0x800401FD: Object is not connected to server.
First-chance exception at 0x00007ffe4f86ab78 in ONENOTE.EXE: 0x800401FD: Object is not connected to server.
First-chance exception at 0x00007ffe4f86ab78 in ONENOTE.EXE: 0x800401FD: Object is not connected to server.
```

Also, since reading up more I think me simply copying my dll into the install folder `program files\[manufacturer]\[application]` (as I don't have an installer) was not enough. I've now executed this against my dll

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319> .\RegAsm.exe
```

and it came back with

```
Microsoft .NET Framework Assembly Registration Utility version 4.0.30319.33440
for Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Types registered successfully
```

Is there anything else I should be doing to register the dll correctly?

Comment: According to the [Engineering OneNote blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2007/05/01/debugging-a-onenote-toolbar-addin-c.aspx), OneNote runs the addins via DllHost.exe.  

If you put MessageBox calls on all your entry points (particularly `OnConnection`), does that appear, or does that fail as well?

Comment: Thanks. No Messagebox shows up I'm afraid. I tried adding both Onenote.exe and DllHost.exe as the startup application before running a debug. In the former OneNote does load but we never get to my add-in even if I try and load it up again when ON is running.

Comment: I've added an edit above to include some further things I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging for OneNote 2013:

Create a file "EnableOneNote2013APILogging.reg"

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00  

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OneNote\Options\Logging] 

"EnableLogging"=dword:00000001 

"EnableTextFileLogging"=dword:0000001

"ttidLogObjectModel"=dword:00000001 

"ttidLogObjectModelAddins"=dword:00000001
```

Create a file "DisableOneNote2013APILogging.reg"

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00  

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OneNote\Options\Logging] 

"EnableLogging"=dword:00000000 

"EnableTextFileLogging"=dword:0000000

"ttidLogObjectModel"=dword:00000000 

"ttidLogObjectModelAddins"=dword:00000000
```

This is based on http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2006/12/08/debugging-the-onenote-api-enable-logging.aspx  but you need to add EnableTextFileLogging ;-).

The logfile is created in %temp%\OneNote.log

For OneNote 2010 change the path in the .reg files to \14.0\ instead of \15.0\